# Stripe payment API problems (Laravel/PHP) secret key

Tags: php, laravel, api

i'm trying to intergrate a stripe api to test payments on my site however im running into a problem regarding payment information specifically when providing a "secret key" it's returning an error that the formatting of the "secret key" is invalid however I copied the key directly from my stripe dashboard.

Has anyone had similar problems / and if found solution would you mind sharing? Thanks.

v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for elements(): clientSecret should be a client secret of the form ${id}*secret*${secret}. You specified: .
at W (v3:1:70490)
at V (v3:1:70561)
at new e (v3:1:270817)
at e. (v3:1:329715)
at e. (v3:1:138782)
at e.o (v3:1:362277)
at Proxy.initialize (StripePayment.vue?0ce4:125:1)

Code:

```
this.elements = this.stripe.elements({ clientSecret: this.clientSecret, appearance })

      const paymentElement = this.elements.create('payment')
      paymentElement.mount('#payment-element')
      this.loadingStripe = false
    },
    async fetchPaymentIntent () {
      await api.post('get-payment-intent', this.cartStore.cart).then((response) => {
        this.clientSecret = response.data.clientSecret
      })
    

 async checkStatus () {
      const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        '$sk_test_(token value hidden for privacy)'
      )
    }

const { paymentIntent } = await this.stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret)
```

Comment: Is it true that u are missing $id, and the word `secret` ?

Comment: you mean to insert it into the "sk_test" key the $id and secret "prefix"

Comment: client secret looks like this `pi_3KIBJd...MLhhr1DIBc5qg_secret_skk...3HIXCXtGjDA`, what are you putting as client secret?

Comment: Fixed it the problem was entirely due to the fact I forgot to enable the REST API functions (GET, PUT...) for users submitting orders - that seemed to fixed it in my case. Thanks for the help nonetheless helped me eliminate a bunch of exploring for potential problems^